# Way to test Live Tile Schedule updates being recieved

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

What is the best way to test a live tile update?

I am setting a schedule and waiting in the emulator, but nothing appears to be happening and i'm trying to find an easy way to force an update?

do i have to wait for the schedule to timeout?

are there any events to subscribe to an update to debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to send an "instant" live tile update to a phone, and it involves using the toast tile notifications followed by a schedule.

- phone opens a httpnotification channel
- phone constructs tile toast xml and uploads it to the above created channel uri
- phone closes the channel

this allows the phone to literally "update" the current tile "right now" as apposed to having to wait an hour to see if everything worked ok.

blog post detailing the above here:

http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2011/04/03/windows-phone-7-live-tile-schedules-ndash-executing-instant-live-tile-updates

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you'll need to wait at least an hour (the minimum `UpdateInterval`) for the tile to be updated.
Yes this makes testing slow. :(

If your application requires the tile be updated when this is initially set you should combine your use of the schedule with tile notifications.

Answer (score 1):

If you "own" the service/server the tile image is being served from then you can some options for logging.

One option is to look in the log file of the web server serving the images and see when the requests were made.  Then you can see if the phone is requesting the tile update as you would expect.

Another option is to dynamically serve the tile image using a .ASHX page (or similar) that writes the PNG byte stream back to the requestor.  In that code you could also log the date and time that the request was made to a DB for later analysis.  I have done this in my apps where I have the phone request a URL with a query parameter e.g. PhoneID, so that you can also log that.  That way you can tell what phone was making the request & when it was made.

Finally there isnt a way to force a tile update using the Scheduled Tile Update method.  For that you need to use Push Notifications.